Expression for imaginary part of a complex number given constraints
Suppose I have two complex numbers $v_1 = a + ib$ and $v_2 = c + id$. I know the magnitudes $|v_1|$ and $|v_2|$ and I know the angle $\theta$ between $v_1$ and $v_2$.
Additionally, I know that $b + c_1d = c_2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are known constants. I would like to obtain an expression for $d$ in terms of all known constants ($a, b, c, d$ are all unknown). I am able to find $d$ using optimization algorithms, but I have not managed to find an explicit expression for it yet.

(possible idea) With an appropriate coordinate axes rotation (that can be expressed in terms of $a,b)$ you can place $v_1$ on the $x$-axis (i.e. the real axis). So maybe try doing what you want to do under the assumption that $b=0.$

Here's a very bad algebraic way to do it.
Let us state the known quantities first. We have $$|v_1|^2=a^2+b^2=:k_1$$ $$|v_2|^2=c^2+d^2=:k_2$$ From the angle, we have $\cos\theta=\frac{ac+bd}{\sqrt{k_1k_2}}$ implying that we also know $$\sqrt{k_1k_2}\cos\theta=ac+bd=:k_3$$
We also know that for some known constants $c_1,c_2$ we have $$b+c_1d=c_2$$

Now we first eliminate $b$ using the last equation to get $$b=c_2-c_1d$$
Then we solve for $a$ and $c$ using the first and second equations $$a=\sqrt{k_1-(c_2-c_1d)^2}$$ $$c=\sqrt{k_2-d^2}$$ Plugging all of them into the third equation, we get $$\sqrt{k_1-(c_2-c_1d)^2}\sqrt{k_2-d^2}+(c_2-c_1d)d=k_3$$ Taking the second term from the left to the right and then squaring and simplifying should give (if my calculations are right) $$(2k_3c_1+k_1+k_2c_1^2)d^2-(2k_3c_2+2k_2c_2c_1)d+(k_3^2-k_1k_2+k_2c_2^2)=0$$ This is a quadratic in $d$ and can be solved exactly.
